# Find nested folders inside /Views in Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to organize my Leaf views inside the `Views` directory, but am unable to create nested directories inside `Views`. I have a header like this

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/test">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The `/test` is actually contained in `Views/TestFolder`, because I maybe thought it recursively searched inside the `Views` folder, but which was not the case. If I try accessing the `test` page I get the following error (which I guess makes perfectly sense):

```
{
  "error": true,
  "reason": "No file was found at path: /Users/eirik/Documents/Utvikling/Jobb/AaseSoftware/Resources/Views/test.leaf"
}
```

I also don't know how I should define the route for this in `routes.swift`. Right now I'm just doing this:

```
router.get("/test") { req -> Future<View> in
    return try req.view().render("test")
}
```

but I guess it only looks for a `test.leaf` file directly inside `Views`. How can I put Leaf files in nested folders inside `Views`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**req.view()** always points to the default folder. If you go to LeafProvider class, you will see the default setting as below.

```
viewsDir: dir.workDir + "Resources/Views"
```

For your case, you need to render from the right path `render("TestFolder/test")`. See the code below.

```
 router.get("/test") { req -> Future<View> in
        return try req.view().render("TestFolder/test")
    }
```

Comment: I thought I'd tried this and it failed on me, but trying it again somehow made it work. Thanks! Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: Great..Some time it is handy to run: "vapor update -y" if any changes made in package/folder structure.